# How can I use COCOAPI/PyCOCOTools to evaluate the performance of Tensorflow Lite models

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I have used the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to train models on a custom dataset. The tensorflow object detection API also allows evaluating the trained models on a test set and gives results in the [COCO eval format](https://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval).  An example output from the evaluation can be seen here:

[Evaluation output from Tensorflow Object Detection API reporting the MSCOCO metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQLvi.jpg)

In this image, there are results such as mAP @ 0.5 IoU and mAP @ 0.75 IoU. It also reports the AR (Average Recall). It also reports an overall mAP.

After training my model, I have converted the models to Tensorflow Lite and I have applied post-training quantization on the model. Now I want to calculate similar metrics for my tflite model on my test set.

Can someone guide me on how I can go about doing this? I am trying to understand how I can use the [COCOAPI](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi) to do this but so far I am not sure how.

A related question is, can someone please tell where I can find documentation for the [COCOAPI](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi)? I have searched everywhere and I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look to this kernel, it uses PyCOCOTools to evaluate metrics of the object detection model.

Comment: Thanks for your response
@tkarahan which kernel are you referring to? I think you might have forgotten to add the link in your comment

Comment: Yeah it seems so, sorry. :) Here is the link:https://www.kaggle.com/pestipeti/competition-metric-map-0-4